# Replacing varying length text over multiple lines in Vim

Tags: vim, replace, vi

Suppose I have a text file open in Vim:

```
Hello Tom. How's your mom?
HellO Sam. Pass me the Jam.
Hell0 Jim. Do you know Vim?
```

I can replace the three names with "friend" using the Visual block trick. But what if the three names were of different length?

```
Hello Kat. You're not fat...
HellO Mike. Where's Pike?
Hell0 James. Hunger games?
```

Is it possible to replace Cat, Mike and James with "friend"? How about if they were surrounded by the same characters, e.g. html tags?

```
Hello <Steph>. You seen Jeff?
HellO <Mat>. Here's your hat.
Hell0 <Jenny>. Got a penny?
```

And if those were doable/easy, is there a way to do it for a single paragraph out of similar paragraphs in a file? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what if the three names were of different length?

```
:%s/\m\w\+\ze\./friend/
```

This replaces the word before the first period on each line.

> How about if they were surrounded by the same characters, e.g. html tags?

```
:%s/\m\w\+\ze>\./friend/
```

This replaces the word before the first pair `>.` on each line.

Also:

```
:%s/\m\<\%(Steph\|Mat\|Jenny\)\>/friend/
```

This replaces the first occurrence of (either) `Steph`, `Mat`, and `Jenny` on each line.

> is there a way to do it for a single paragraph out of similar paragraphs in a file?

Depending on what you mean by "paragraph", you can use `:global`.  Or not. :)

Comment: Hey thank you so much for that. If possible, can you outline briefly how they work? I understand it is a sed substitution, but what are the \m, \w and \% for?

Comment: Also \+ and \ze

Comment: And by paragraph I meant multiple lines but not all.

Comment: @DDauS launch Vim and `:h \m`, `:h \w` and so on :)

Comment: @sidyll Thanks a bunch, this `:h` thing will help out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
:%norm WcWFriend

:  ...... command mode
%  ...... whole file
norm .... normal mode
W ....... big word (jump to)
cW ...... change word (change it)
```

Obs: Big words include "-" separated and html tags